# Kotlin: Function that returns a generic type. What If I do not know which concrete type should get returned?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have the following type:

```
class Images<T : Image>(
    val images: List<T>,
    val totalCount: Int
)
```

So the list here can only contain objects which are inheriting from `Image`.

Now I have an interface:

```
interface ImageService<T : Image> {
    fun getNewImages(offset: Int, limit: Int): Images<T>

    fun getNextImage(): Image
}
```

And a concrete implementation:

```
class NumberImageService : ImageService<NumberImage> {
    override fun getNewImages(offset: Int, limit: Int): Images<NumberImage> {
        // return something
    }

    override fun getNextImage(): NumberImage {
        // return something
    }
}
```

So far, so good. Now I have another class where I decide which concrete implementation to use based on an enum input:

```
class ImageQueryResolver : GraphQLQueryResolver {
    fun getNewImages(input: ImageInput, offset: Int, limit: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE): Images {
        return when (input.imageType) {
            ImageEnum.NUMBER ->
                numberImageService.getNewImages(offset, limit)
            ImageEnum.LETTER ->
                letterImageService.getNewImages(offset, limit)
        }
    }

    fun getNextImage(input: ImageInput): Image {
        // return something
    }
}
```

So this is giving me an error because the return type of `getNewImages`, which is `Images` needs to have an argument:

```
One type argument expected for class Images<T : Image>
```

But which argument do I need to use now?

Comment: You can have `ImageQueryResolver#getNewImages` return `Images<out Image>`.

Comment: This works. Thank you! I will read why it works though ^^

Comment: This reference may help: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html. If you're familiar with Java it's similar to using `Images<? extends Image>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, you can use `Images<out Image>` as the return type. This is basically saying the implementation may use `Image` or a subtype of `Image`. If you're familiar with Java then it's similar to using `Images<? extends Image>`.

Since your `Images` interface only ever produces objects of type `T` another option is to use *declaration-site variance* instead of *use-site variance*. In other words, you could have:

```
interface Images<out T : Image> {
    // methods...
}
```

Which will let you use `Images<Image>` as the return type:

```
fun getNewImages(input: ImageInput, offset: Int, limit: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE): Images<Image> {
    return when (input.imageType) {
        ImageEnum.NUMBER ->
            numberImageService.getNewImages(offset, limit)
        ImageEnum.LETTER ->
            letterImageService.getNewImages(offset, limit)
    }
}
```

---

Here's the reference on generics in Kotlin: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify that argument, because Images is generic. So, I would suggest one of two:

1) `Images<out Image>` -> return type is a subtype of Image

2) `Images<*>` -> I dont care what generic type is there

I think first solution is better (we bounded that value, so we know more what's going all) ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
fun <T : Image> getNewImages(input: ImageInput, offset: Int, limit: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE): Images<T> {
  return when (input.imageType) {
    ImageEnum.NUMBER ->
      numberImageService.getNewImages(offset, limit)
    ImageEnum.LETTER ->
      letterImageService.getNewImages(offset, limit)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thx for your reply. That does not work. It leads to a type missmatch between `Images<T>` and `Images<NumberImage>`. However, putting in `Images<out T>` as return type for that function works.